Traversing through a directed acyclic graph asynchronously with a controller-worker architecture without using busy waits in Python
I have a Graph class made up of Node class objects and has a special start_node and end_node. The Node class has a method run which is essentially just a wrapper for a callable func which is an attribute of Node objects. Node objects also have children and parents lists as attributes.
I need to call run on all the nodes, which form a DAG. However, I need to do this asynchronously, i.e. all in a different process. I need the return values from calling run and need to run some code dependent on the values returned by func.
Currently, I have a controller-worker architecture in mind where the controller process traverses the DAG starting from the start_node and forks a new process for each node and calls run on the node when it sees that all of its parents have returned successfully. However, I do not wish to use a busy wait in the controller process. I want that the controller process blocks till it receives a signal (maybe using the Event class of multiprocessing) and when it receives a signal from a process signifying its successful finish, it either starts its children (assuming all the parents of the child have also finished successfully) or updates some data structures in the memory space of the controller process to keep a track of which nodes have been visited till/run till now.
Whatever method I have tried are inefficient either because:

They do not utilize multi-processing effectively. I want all the nodes which can be run at a particular time to run in different processes. They either run only 1 worker process or utilize sleep to block the controller process.
They use a busy wait to await the completion of worker processes.
They are incorrect in some schedules, and one can design a series of context-switches in which the updates are wrong.

I am free to modify the signature of the run method or the architecture as long it gets the job done efficiently. The run for different nodes can take arbitrary time, anything from a few milliseconds to hours, so the design needs to be robust enough to handle any scheduling algorithms. I am using Python for this task and am free to use any libraries I wish.
